# Generate mapping between two isomorphic graphs

Tags: python, graph-theory, networkx

Two graphs G1 and G2 are isomorphic (is_isomorphic(G1, G2) => True) but have different attributes on each node. How can I obtain a mapping or dictionary between the value of attribute X from node Y on graph G1 and the value of attribute X from the "structurally-equivalent" node Y'.

Best,
Eric

Comment: You could use the `get_node_attributes` function and keep the results in tuples.  What have you tried? What is not working?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I don't know how i can identify the corresponding node pairs. I can't use get_node_attributes if I don't know the nodes that correspond to one another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the advanced interface to the VF2 isomorphism algorithm. 
https://networkx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/algorithms.isomorphism.vf2.html

It will give you the matching.

```
>>> from networkx.algorithms import isomorphism
>>> G1 = nx.path_graph(4)
>>> G2 = nx.path_graph(4)
>>> GM = isomorphism.GraphMatcher(G1,G2)
>>> GM.is_isomorphic()
True

GM.mapping stores the isomorphism mapping from G1 to G2.

>>> GM.mapping
{0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3}
```

Comment: Perfect! This is what I am looking for. Thanks for the reply.